# Convert ftp command line cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp

How can I translate the following cURL line to php cURL.

```
curl -v --cacert [linkToCertificate] -k --ftp-ssl -T "[fileToUpload]" -P - ftp://[user]:[password]@[URL]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); #-v
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '-');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server . $source_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftp_user . ':' . $ftp_password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

//SSL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $ftp_certificate);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLPROTO_FTP);
```

Comment: how bout `exec('curl -v --cacert [linkToCertificate] -k --ftp-ssl -T "[fileToUpload]" -P - ftp://[user]:[password]@[URL]');`

Comment: I am not able to exec() since curl is not install on command line atm.

Updated description with what I have tried

Comment: @Adelphia: Please tell me that was meant to be a joke. It's is a terrible idea to run commandline tools from code when there is a library you can use.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: justify your claim. why use a high-level php library when you can save resources using lower-level options? The only justic=fication I can think of for your statement is portability, barring that i don't see why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Especially considering how bad PHP's shell functions are (you have to pass a string instead of an argv array) it's quite easy  to end up with shell command/argument injection vulnerabilities. Also, there's the overhead of launching a new process (even though that's probably negligible when you network I/O). Maintainability is another thing. What's more readable? A long shell command or a clean list of setopt calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and answer to my issue.
The issue was that curl run the ftp connection in passive mode. And I needed it to run in active mode.

My solution was therefore to add this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, 0);
```

Full curl solution:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server . $destination_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftp_user . ':' . $ftp_password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($source_file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $ftp_certificate);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_ALL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_SSL);
```